# Cannot save user name after I add a post_user_name column to the post table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have a rails practice project like a blog website user devise gem on it through rails 4.
Its works fine before. And I already have `user_name` in comments and it works fine. But when I add a colomn `post_user_name` through `FixColumnName`.
it just cannot save the user name and connot show it both in posts and comments! How could it be?
(I have a `post_user_name` in post table and `user_name` in comment table. They are not related but all use devise's `current_user.username`.)

its my posts index erb:

```
<h1>Listing posts</h1>
<% if user_signed_in? %>
     <div class="field">
     <%= link_to 'Create a New Post', new_post_path, :class => "btn btn-success btn-sm" %>
     </div>
  <% end %>

<% @posts.each do |post| %>
<div class="post thumbnail">
  <h3><%= post.name %></h3>
  <div><h5>edit by <%= post.post_user_name %></h5></div>
  <div><%= (post.descriptopm).html_safe %></div>

  <% if user_signed_in? %>
  <div class="bottom-bottoms">
    <%= link_to 'Display', post, :class => "btn btn-info btn-xs" %>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post), :class => "btn btn-info btn-xs" %>
    <%= link_to 'Delete', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, :class => "btn btn-info btn-xs" %>
  </div>
  <% end %>

  <h3>Comments</h3>
  <% post.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <div>
      <p><strong><%= comment.user_name %></strong> : <%= (comment.body).html_safe %></p>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= bootstrap_form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
  <% if @comment.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@comment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this comment from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @comment.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <% if user_signed_in? %>
  <div class="field">
  <%= f.text_field :user_name, value: current_user.username, :disabled => true %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
  <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </div>
  <%= f.hidden_field :post_id, value: post.id %>
  <div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
  <% end %>

<% end %>

</div>
<% end %>
```

the textfield in post's form:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.text_field :post_user_name, value: current_user.username, :disabled => true, label: "Your Name" %>
</div>
```

my post controller

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:name, :post_user_name, :descriptopm)
end
```

my comment controller

```
def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:user_name, :body, :post_id)
end
```

Comment: just a colomn for saving name

Comment: Could you be clearer about what's not working?

Comment: thats okay  
I found it by my self

Answer (score 2):

take off the `:disabled => true` in the form and it works!!
But I really don't know why? QQ

Comment: The W3 specification for forms distinguishes **disabled** and **read-only** and makes it clear that disabled inputs should not be submitted with the form data.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you some more information, let me give you some ideas...

--

**Associations**

When you mention you are calling a `user_name` attribute for *each* of the `Post` and `Comment` models, it made me flinch.

The reason is that if you do this, you're completely going against the [DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) & [Single Source Of Truth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Source_of_Truth) principles of software development - which means that you need to keep one single reference to both methods / functions, and data throughout your app

When you call `post.post_user_name` with an attribute in your `posts` table, you're setting yourself up for trouble:

--

[**Foreign Keys**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key)

Instead of populating the `user_name` columns as you have, you should instead focus on using [`foreign_keys`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) in your tables, allowing you to reference objects in associated tables. This is where [ActiveRecord associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) come in:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :posts
   has_many :comments
end

#app/models/post.rb
Class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   delegate :name, to: :user, prefix: true #-> @post.user_name

   #fields id | user_id | title | content | created_at | updated_at 
end

#app/models/comment.rb
Class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   delegate :name, to: :user, prefix: true #-> @comment.user_name

   #fields id | user_id | title | content | created_at | updated_at 
end
```

As you can see, if you populate the `foreign_key` (in our case `user_id`), it will give us the ability to reference the corresponding objects from the other data tables. This means that instead of accessing the `@post` object's "username" directly, if you've associated it correctly, you'll be able to reference the `username` like this: `@post.user_name`

--

**Setup**

The trick to getting this setup to work is to simply set the `foreign_key`, either with an object, or with a value:

```
#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
Class PostsController < ApplicationController
   def create
      current_user.posts.create(post_params)
      ...
   end
end
```

This will set all the associations for you as you need

Comment: actually I take off the :disabled => true in the form and it works!!
But I really don't know why? QQ

Comment: who? did I misclick somthing?